# How do I find the Undaunted guild in Dominion regions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

As a new Altmer, I read some tips for newbie players and joined the **Fighter** and **Mages** guilds in *Vulkhel Guard*. The hints also recommend joining the **Undaunted** guild, but I can't find it.

I haven't been to towns other than *Vulkhel Guard* and *Kenarthi's Roost*, so I don't know if they were removed from the game or only have branches in some more advanced city or the PvP area. How do I find/join the Undaunted, if they are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aldmeri Dominion characters can find [Turuk Redclaws](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Online:Turuk_Redclaws) in the [Salted Wings Tavern](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Online:Salted_Wings_Tavern) in Vulkhel Guard to start the Undaunted quest for the region (which will immediately grant you the skill line, even if you don't pursue the quest right away).

If I recall correctly, he's on the second floor and there isn't much other reason for you to ever go up there, which could explain why you missed him.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I was trying to find the guild using their map symbol that I saw online. I'm too new to have actually explored every building in town, busy learning the ropes ;)